# Image does not load in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm really sorry for asking this question. It's couple of hours I'm trying to solve a problem. I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I have a css file in which I refer to tow images. Here is the code:

```
.white
{
    background-image: url("images/site/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
}
.normal
{
    background-image: url("images/site/glyphicons-halflings.png");
}
```

I have also added these images to `Content\images\site` folder. But it does not load the images and css does not work. I can see these tow error messages in firebug:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -http://localhost:38544/Content/images/site/glyphicons-halflings.png"
>
> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -http://localhost:38544/Content/images/site/glyphicons-halflings-white.png"

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't misspelled the filenames? Your code seems fine.

Comment: It's going to make me crazy. I copied the file name.

Comment: Is this happening locally in IISExpress (or Cassini if that's what you are using)? Or when you deployed your application on IIS?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. The only 2 possible causes are: 1. misspelled filename and/or path and 2. The file doesn't exist at the specified location.

Comment: You were right. Misspeling

Comment: Alright, let me post this as answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

404 error is a very strong indication that you have misspelled the image filename in your CSS or forgot to actually copy the image in the specified folder.